# can KY jelly be used in a pinch if no silicone plumbers lubricant is available? this is NO joke!

Tags: faucet, bathtub, delta

The tub faucet is in pieces right now and wanted to have repaired before the man of the house returns from his daily labors. I've replaced before but used no lubricant. That may be why it needs repaired again after 5 years. Everything was put together right but the faucet handle is extremely tight. Referred to the good ole internet but that question has never come up! REALLY???

Comment: Do you have hard (mineral and deposit rich) water?

Answer (score 6):

KY is water soluble, so would be pointless as a lubricant for plumbing fixtures. In a pinch, *maybe* petroleum jelly would work.

Comment: Petroleum jelly isn't any good for plumbing either because it will eat away at rubber 'O' rings and other seals.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson I don't know the real answer to that...I hear people debate that all the time. My (limited) understanding is that petroleum jelly will eat away at natural rubber, but most "rubber" seals and o-rings these days are not made from natural rubber. I'd still prefer silicon grease in any case. :)

Comment: This totally depends in which country this brothel is in.